# NRF24L01 receiver flooded with data packets

Tags: arduino-nano, nrf24l01+

Following [this tutorial](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/simple-nrf24l01-2-4ghz-transceiver-demo/405123) I attempted making an NRF transmitter and receiver using an Arduino Nano. On the transmitter side I used the following code:

```cpp
// SimpleTx - the master or the transmitter

#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>


#define CE_PIN   9
#define CSN_PIN 10

const byte slaveAddress[5] = {'R','x','A','A','A'};


RF24 radio(CE_PIN, CSN_PIN); // Create a Radio

char dataToSend[10] = "Message 0";
char txNum = '0';


unsigned long currentMillis;
unsigned long prevMillis;
unsigned long txIntervalMillis = 1000; // send once per second


void setup() {

    Serial.begin(9600);

    Serial.println("SimpleTx Starting");

    radio.begin();
    radio.setDataRate( RF24_250KBPS );
    radio.setRetries(3,5); // delay, count
    radio.openWritingPipe(slaveAddress);
}

//====================

void loop() {
    currentMillis = millis();
    if (currentMillis - prevMillis >= txIntervalMillis) {
        send();
        prevMillis = millis();
    }
}

//====================

void send() {

    bool rslt;
    rslt = radio.write( &dataToSend, sizeof(dataToSend) );
        // Always use sizeof() as it gives the size as the number of bytes.
        // For example if dataToSend was an int sizeof() would correctly return 2

    Serial.print("Data Sent ");
    Serial.print(dataToSend);
    if (rslt) {
        Serial.println("  Acknowledge received");
        updateMessage();
    }
    else {
        Serial.println("  Tx failed");
    }
}

//================

void updateMessage() {
        // so you can see that new data is being sent
    txNum += 1;
    if (txNum > '9') {
        txNum = '0';
    }
    dataToSend[8] = txNum;
}
```

The serial monitor prints

```
13:05:22.966 -> Data Sent Message 3  SimpleTx Starting
13:05:25.437 -> Data Sent Message 0  Acknowledge received
13:05:26.436 -> Data Sent Message 1  Acknowledge received
13:05:27.434 -> Data Sent Message 2  Acknowledge received
13:05:28.432 -> Data Sent Message 3  Acknowledge received
13:05:29.432 -> Data Sent Message 4  Acknowledge received
13:05:30.432 -> Data Sent Message 5  Acknowledge received
13:05:31.427 -> Data Sent Message 6  Acknowledge received
```

at 1 second intervals. I assume this points to an 'okay' transmitter. On the receiver side, I used the code

```cpp
// SimpleRx - the slave or the receiver

#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>

#define CE_PIN   9
#define CSN_PIN 10

const byte thisSlaveAddress[5] = {'R','x','A','A','A'};

RF24 radio(CE_PIN, CSN_PIN);

char dataReceived[10]; // this must match dataToSend in the TX
bool newData = false;

//===========

void setup() {

    Serial.begin(9600);

    Serial.println("SimpleRx Starting");
    radio.begin();
    radio.setDataRate( RF24_250KBPS );
    radio.openReadingPipe(1, thisSlaveAddress);
    radio.startListening();
}

//=============

void loop() {
    getData();
    showData();
}

//==============

void getData() {
    if ( radio.available() ) {
        radio.read( &dataReceived, sizeof(dataReceived) );
        newData = true;
    }
}

void showData() {
    if (newData == true) {
        Serial.print("Data received ");
        Serial.println(dataReceived);
        newData = false;
    }
}
```

And the receiver gets flooded with data packets

```
13:06:20.318 -> Data received⸮SimpleRx Starting
13:06:21.798 -> Data received 
13:06:21.831 -> Data received 
13:06:21.831 -> Data received 
13:06:21.864 -> Data received
```

The post also mentions that this is due to "most likely the Arduino is not communicating properly with its nRF24." Following the recommendations of post #30, later in the thread, the output of radio.printDetails() for the transmitter is

```
19:43:56.897 -> CheckConnection Starting
19:43:56.897 -> 
19:43:56.897 -> FIRST WITH THE DEFAULT ADDRESSES aftCheckConnection Starting
19:43:58.355 -> 
19:43:58.355 -> FIRST WITH THE DEFAULT ADDRESSES after power on
19:43:58.422 ->   Note that RF24 does NOT reset when Arduino resets - only when power is removed
19:43:58.488 ->   If the numbers are mostly 0x00 or 0xff it means that the Arduino is not
19:43:58.574 ->      communicating with the nRF24
19:43:58.621 -> 
19:43:58.621 -> SPI Speedz  = 10 Mhz
19:43:58.654 -> STATUS      = 0x7f RX_DR=1 TX_DS=1 MAX_RT=1 RX_P_NO=7 TX_FULL=1
19:43:58.721 -> RX_ADDR_P0-1    = 0xffffffffff 0xffffffffff
19:43:58.754 -> RX_ADDR_P2-5    = 0xff 0xff 0x7f 0xff
19:43:58.788 -> TX_ADDR     = 0xffffffff7f
19:43:58.821 -> RX_PW_P0-6  = 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
19:43:58.854 -> EN_AA       = 0x00
19:43:58.887 -> EN_RXADDR   = 0x7f
19:43:58.887 -> RF_CH       = 0x00
19:43:58.920 -> RF_SETUP    = 0x00
19:43:58.920 -> CONFIG      = 0x00
19:43:58.954 -> DYNPD/FEATURE   = 0x00 0x00
19:43:58.954 -> Data Rate   = 1 MBPS
19:43:58.987 -> Model       = nRF24L01+
19:43:59.020 -> CRC Length  = Disabled
19:43:59.020 -> PA Power    = PA_MIN
19:43:59.053 -> ARC     = 0
19:43:59.053 -> 
19:43:59.053 -> 
19:43:59.053 -> AND NOW WITH ADDRESS AAAxR  0x41 41 41 78 52   ON P1
19:43:59.120 ->  and 250KBPS data rate
19:43:59.154 -> 
19:43:59.154 -> SPI Speedz  = 10 Mhz
19:43:59.186 -> STATUS      = 0x00 RX_DR=0 TX_DS=0 MAX_RT=0 RX_P_NO=0 TX_FULL=0
19:43:59.253 -> RX_ADDR_P0-1    = 0x0000000000 0x0000000000
19:43:59.286 -> RX_ADDR_P2-5    = 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
19:43:59.320 -> TX_ADDR     = 0x0000000000
19:43:59.353 -> RX_PW_P0-6  = 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
19:43:59.386 -> EN_AA       = 0x00
19:43:59.419 -> EN_RXADDR   = 0x00
19:43:59.419 -> RF_CH       = 0x00
19:43:59.452 -> RF_SETUP    = 0x00
19:43:59.452 -> CONFIG      = 0x00
19:43:59.486 -> DYNPD/FEATURE   = 0x00 0x00
19:43:59.486 -> Data Rate   = 1 MBPS
19:43:59.519 -> Model       = nRF24L01+
19:43:59.552 -> CRC Length  = Disabled
19:43:59.552 -> PA Power    = PA_MIN
19:43:59.585 -> ARC     = 0
19:43:59.585 -> 
19:43:59.585 ->
```

The same sketch when uploaded on the receiver gives,

```
19:48:38.260 -> CheckConnection Starting
19:48:38.260 -> 
19:48:38.260 -> 
19:48:38.260 -> 
19:48:38.260 -> FIRST WITH THE DEFAULT ADDRESSES aftCheckConnection Starting
19:48:39.708 -> 
19:48:39.708 -> FIRST WITH THE DEFAULT ADDRESSES after power on
19:48:39.774 ->   Note that RF24 does NOT reset when Arduino resets - only when power is removed
19:48:39.841 ->   If the numbers are mostly 0x00 or 0xff it means that the Arduino is not
19:48:39.941 ->      communicating with the nRF24
19:48:39.974 -> 
19:48:39.974 -> SPI Speedz  = 10 Mhz
19:48:40.008 -> STATUS      = 0x00 RX_DR=0 TX_DS=0 MAX_RT=0 RX_P_NO=0 TX_FULL=0
19:48:40.075 -> RX_ADDR_P0-1    = 0x0000000000 0x0000000000
19:48:40.109 -> RX_ADDR_P2-5    = 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
19:48:40.141 -> TX_ADDR     = 0x0000000000
19:48:40.175 -> RX_PW_P0-6  = 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
19:48:40.208 -> EN_AA       = 0x00
19:48:40.242 -> EN_RXADDR   = 0x00
19:48:40.242 -> RF_CH       = 0x00
19:48:40.274 -> RF_SETUP    = 0x00
19:48:40.274 -> CONFIG      = 0x00
19:48:40.308 -> DYNPD/FEATURE   = 0x00 0x00
19:48:40.308 -> Data Rate   = 1 MBPS
19:48:40.341 -> Model       = nRF24L01+
19:48:40.374 -> CRC Length  = Disabled
19:48:40.374 -> PA Power    = PA_MIN
19:48:40.407 -> ARC     = 0
19:48:40.407 -> 
19:48:40.407 -> 
19:48:40.407 -> AND NOW WITH ADDRESS AAAxR  0x41 41 41 78 52   ON P1
19:48:40.474 ->  and 250KBPS data rate
19:48:40.508 -> 
19:48:40.508 -> SPI Speedz  = 10 Mhz
19:48:40.541 -> STATUS      = 0x00 RX_DR=0 TX_DS=0 MAX_RT=0 RX_P_NO=0 TX_FULL=0
19:48:40.607 -> RX_ADDR_P0-1    = 0x0000000000 0x0000000000
19:48:40.640 -> RX_ADDR_P2-5    = 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
19:48:40.674 -> TX_ADDR     = 0x0000000000
19:48:40.707 -> RX_PW_P0-6  = 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
19:48:40.740 -> EN_AA       = 0x00
19:48:40.773 -> EN_RXADDR   = 0x00
19:48:40.773 -> RF_CH       = 0x00
19:48:40.806 -> RF_SETUP    = 0x00
19:48:40.806 -> CONFIG      = 0x00
19:48:40.840 -> DYNPD/FEATURE   = 0x00 0x00
19:48:40.840 -> Data Rate   = 1 MBPS
19:48:40.873 -> Model       = nRF24L01+
19:48:40.906 -> CRC Length  = Disabled
19:48:40.906 -> PA Power    = PA_MIN
19:48:40.939 -> ARC     = 0
19:48:40.939 -> 
19:48:40.939 ->
```

There is some miscommunication as claimed by that post. I tried changing the pins of CE, CSN to 7,8 but the problem persisted for the receiver. I changed the power supply to the NRF using two alkaline AA batteries, but that didn't solve the problem either. I also connected a 10 μF capacitor between the power supply pins of the NRF, but no luck.
Next, I tried changing the NRF module. I used an NRF module which was working correctly as a transmitter(printing "Data Sent Message X  Acknowledge received") at 1 second, as intervals as a receiver in place, still the same problem.

Any help would oblige.

P.S: I am using Arduino clones, but they work for other purposes. The NRF's have "NRF24L01" stamped on the chip, and seem to be fine.

Comment: The ```radio.printDetails()``` information are coming from the sender or the receiver ?

Comment: According to [reply #30](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/simple-nrf24l01-2-4ghz-transceiver-demo/405123/30) on the Arduino Forum thread "[Simple nRF24L01+ 2.4GHz transceiver demo](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/simple-nrf24l01-2-4ghz-transceiver-demo/405123/)", `radio.printDetails()` is run twice: once for unintialised and a second time for initialised. This should give you two sets of results, but you've only posted one set in your question. Are both sets of results identical?

Comment: @Vincent, sorry for the incomplete information. I have updated the question. What strikes me, is that [#reply #30](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/simple-nrf24l01-2-4ghz-transceiver-demo/405123/30) sets radio.setDataRate( RF24_250KBPS ); but radio.printDetails(); report Data Rate   = 1 MBPS.

Comment: @tim, sorry for the incomplete details too. I have posted both sets now. They are identical for the receiver, but STATUS, RX_ADDR_P0-1, RX_ADDR_P2-5, TX_ADDR and EN_RXADDR differ for the transmitter.

Comment: @RanjitPal About DataRate, nRF24L01 can transmit only with 1MBPS or 2MBPS, while nRF24L01+ (upgraded version) can also transmit with 250KBPS (which is useful for polluted environment or longer distance communication). This is why you can not set your nRF24L01 to a 250KBPS datarate. But it surprises me that the ```printDetails()``` command indicates the upgraded version to be honest. The pipe1 address also remains the same even if you execute ```openReadingPipe(1, thisSlaveAddress)``` which is another problem.

Comment: @RanjitPal To me, the problem might come from ```setRetries(3,5)``` (5 retries with 1ms interval) while AutoAcknowledgment (= AA) is disabled. When AA is disabled, the transmitter module automaticaly return true even if the receiver hasn't received anything. In your case, the receiver seems to receive something, but not the message *Message x* you have sent, since nothing is displayed on the serial monitor. Try to enabled AA, or change to ```setRetries(1,1)```.

Comment: @Vincent, I funny thing I notice is that the serial prints "Data Received" even when I dont have a transmitter connected. I mean if I just power the Arduino and the NRF for the receiver, "Data Received" is printed in the serial.

Comment: Following the [Getting Started](https://github.com/nRF24/RF24/blob/master/examples/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.ino) Example, it prints "radio hardware is not responding!!". Well radio.begin() returns a false.